# Last Date with a filter is not showing all dates in Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have created two measures to show the last date a record was entered and how many days since that date.
I needed to add conditions for each classification (FAC,LTI, RWDC)>> Those are my classifications as an example.

**I started with LTI Classification:**

```
Last LTI Date =  CALCULATE (
MAXA ('Zero Harm'[Date] ),
LASTNONBLANK ( 'Zero Harm'[Date],
MAXA ( 'Zero Harm'[Date]) ), 
FILTER('Zero Harm','Zero Harm'[Classification] = "LTI"))
```

The above should show me the last date of an entry.

```
Days Since Last LTI = IF( CALCULATE( DATEDIFF( [Last LTI Date] ,
 Today(),DAY) + 0 , 'Zero Harm'[Classification] = "LTI") = BLANK(), ">
 5 Years", CALCULATE( DATEDIFF( [Last Date] , [Today],DAY) + 0 , 'Zero
 Harm'[Classification] = "LTI"))
```

---

I have the same two measures for each classification.

In the output, it give me all the days since last correctly, but for some records I am not able to see the last date? not sure why..

[image: The Highlighted, I was able to know days since last but the date not showing]